# Can I say two-series to describe a series of two events?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I am presenting two talks on two different dates, and I would like to describe the first one as the first of a two-series talk. Is two-series talk a word that can be used with this meaning? Googling it I found zero references.
This [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210177/a-series-of-three-is-trilogy-a-series-of-two-is) looks similar and I am thinking of changing to use a two-part series, but isn't it maybe a little too cumbersome?

Comment: Your suggestion sounds as if there are two *series* - but there are two *talks* in *one* series.

Comment: I was using two as an adjective, two-series, not two series, which I meant as a series with two events. But I do realise it is far from perfect and prone to confusion, that is why I posted the question. :)

Comment: I know what you meant - but even as a compound adjective, the "two" is still referring to "series" - NOT to "talk".  You could have said a *two-talk series* - but NOT a *two-series talk*, which means that there are *two series* in *one talk*.

Comment: I was probably thinking of two-talk series, you are right, and came up with a meaningless hybrid. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90944/what-is-the-word-for-a-series-of-two-related-works?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, "the first of a pair of talks," would be much less cumbersome, and easily readable.

Series does have the implication that there are a few, i.e. 3 or more.

Comment: That does sound better.